# How to only allow SELECT, INSERT in SQL Server 15?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to adjust the permissions of a SQL Server table so that only `SELECT` and `INSERT` commands are possible for users. The execution of all other commands (e.g. `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...) should not be possible.

I have tried the following:

```
USE MyDB
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
(
    colA INT,
    colB INT
);

CREATE ROLE my_role;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON OBJECT::dbo.TestTable TO my_role;
DENY UPDATE, DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.TestTable TO my_role;

ALTER ROLE my_role ADD MEMBER user1;
```

But the permissions didn't seem to have changed. Everything is still possible. I've read, that Ownership chains can be the cause, but even if I create a new schema with public as owner and create the table on this schema it's the same like above.

How can I set table permissions that will work?

Comment: Whats SQL Server 15? You need to run `select @@version`

Comment: Who is the owner of TestTable? Is it `my_role`?

Comment: Is the user also in the `db_owner` role members? Or other roles that grant delete and update privileges?

Comment: Sounds like, to me, that the `USER` is part of other database `ROLE`s, has been granted other permissions *explicitly*, or they are a `sysadmin` (I really hope not the latter).

Comment: The SQL Server version is "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - 15.0.2101.7".

The Table owner is dbo (Query was: SELECT p.name AS table_owner FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id INNER JOIN sys.database_principals p ON s.principal_id = p.principal_id WHERE t.name = 'TestTable';)

The user is not sysadmin, and it has only the role "my_role" (SQL: EXEC sp_helpuser 'user1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user1 got the sysadmin role through some weird Active Directory groups....